# Data stored in service cannot be retrieved later

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I'm just getting started on angular, and I feel like a few details are preventing me from getting this to work right!
I set up a simple service like this:

```
mySystem.factory('userAcsService', [function() {
    var user;

    return {
        getuser: function () {
            return user;
        },
        setuser: function (value) {
            user = value;   // working fine

            console.log('name: ' + user.name);
        }
    };
}]);
```

The first controller (on `'/User/Search'`) stores that data correctly:

```
mySystem.controller('SearchController', ['$scope', '$route', '$routeParams', '$location', '$http', 'userAcsService', 
    function ($scope, $route, $routeParams, $location, $http, userAcsService) {
        //...
        $scope.details = function (user) {
            userAcsService.setuser(user);   // setting works fine
            window.location.href = '/User/Details';
        };
        //...
    }
]);
```

But then, when I try to retrieve that user, using a different controller (after the redirect to `'/User/Details'`), it's always undefined:

```
mySystem.controller('EditController', ['$scope', '$route', '$routeParams', '$location', '$http', 'userAcsService',
    function ($scope, $route, $routeParams, $location, $http, userAcsService) {
        //...
        $scope.user = userAcsService.getuser(); // always undefined
        alert($scope.user.name);
        //...
    }
]);
```

What is needed for this to work??

**EDIT:** The setter method in my `userAcsService` is only being called once.

Comment: can you show where you call `$scope.details(someRealUser)`. It's certainly called after you ask for `userAcsService.getuser();`

Comment: They're on different pages, `userAcsService.getUser()` is called when I redirect to `'/User/Details'`, it's definitely being called after the setter (also confirmed by debugging).  The problem I have is that I assumed `userAcsService` would be a singleton, and it appears I'm getting a new instance of it, but I don't know how.

Comment: Nothing in what you explain let suppose that AngularJS services may fail to be singletons.

Comment: maybe you should implement a $watch on `userAcsService.user` so as to react when the user is changed.

Comment: your `$scope.user = userAcsService.getuser();` is executed once at the construction of the EditController. That is probably not the good moment if the user has not been set yet.

Comment: @StephaneRolland the user has definitely been set, but on `'/User/Search'`. Even so, I tried putting `$scope.user = userAcsService.getuser();` in a button click, but it's still undefined.

Comment: Please be clearer. `window.location.href` can be set to '/User/Details' not `userAcsService.setuser(...)` which you don't show the code calling it.

Comment: I meant that the user is being set on the page `'/User/Search'`.
And then only after that I try calling the getter, on the page `'/User/Details'`, and by then, the user is undefined.

Comment: this is because `userAcsService.getuser();`is called only when the Controller is constructed.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40192/discussion-between-vitor-m-barbosa-and-stephane-rolland)

Comment: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#methods_$watch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window.location.href = "/User/Details"` will make a full page load, will it not? That means that all your javascript will be reloaded and user will be `undefined`.

For this to work you will need to transition to "/User/Details" without a full page load, probably by building a single page application using angulars router or ui-router https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router.

Comment: Looks like this is it! Thanks!  
This is an asp.net MVC application with lots of APIs throw in, I wanted to avoid making another API call or request to the server, but I guess that will be the way.